# Python: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute

Tags: python

I'm trying to fetch the current stock value using Yahoo Finance API. The only example I've found is in Python and follows here:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def stock_price(symbol: str = "AAPL") -> str:
    url = f"https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{symbol}/"
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    class_ = "My(6px) Pos(r) smartphone_Mt(6px) W(100%)"
    return soup.find("div", class_=class_).find("span").text


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for symbol in "AAPL AMZN IBM GOOG MSFT ORCL".split():
        print(f"Current {symbol:<4} stock price is {stock_price(symbol):>8}")
```

I'm not expert in Python, however I have followed the instructions from the site where the example is available: https://iq.opengenus.org/current-stock-price-in-python/

So I have installed the required libs:

```
python -m pip install requests

pip install beautifulsoup4
```

However when running, I have the following error:

```
$ python3 quote.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "quote.py", line 14, in <module>
    print(f"Current {symbol:<4} stock price is {stock_price(symbol):>8}")
  File "quote.py", line 9, in stock_price
    return soup.find("div", class_=class_).find("span").text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

I have checked the URL requested with one symbol: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL
So it shouldn't return an empty data set.
Can you give me some hints on how to fix it?
Thanks a lot

EDIT: Thanks for your answer, I have found a simpler solution by installing the yahoo_fin:

```
from yahoo_fin import stock_info as si

# get Apple's live quote price
print(si.get_live_price("AAPL"))
```

Comment: How did you check AAPL?  With a regular browser, or with python request?

Comment: `soup.find("div")` returns `None`, so `.find("span")` fails with this exception.

Answer (score 0):

`soup.find("div", class_=class_)` returns the value `None`. `find("span")` fails to work with this exception.
Try to get the first part work

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to be working fine, however, since you are parsing an external, dynamic HTML webpage, you can’t guarantee that it will always retrieve the exact same HTML structure. Therefore, I would recommend adding a try/catch block only to the parsing part.

```
def stock_price(symbol: str = "AAPL") -> str:
    url = f"https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{symbol}/"
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    class_ = "My(6px) Pos(r) smartphone_Mt(6px) W(100%)"
    try:
        result = soup.find("div", class_=class_).find("span").text
    except AttributeError:
        result = "NOT_FOUND"
    return result


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for symbol in "AAPL AMZN IBM GOOG MSFT ORCL".split():
        print(f"Current {symbol:<4} stock price is {stock_price(symbol):>8}")
```